# EE Empty File Field Triggers - The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file

Tags: channel-entries, file-uploads, channel-files

EE 2.8.1, non-required file fields when trying to publish a channel entry all trigger the below error if they are left empty.

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.

Has anyone else come across this or had a fix? I haven't found anything but my Google-fu could be weak.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to me having the php post_max_size set to -1 (unlimited) on my local machine.

The file manager should probably handle this, but it doesn't so I've amended Filemanager.php to the below, which fixes it:

```
public function validate_post_data()
{
    ee()->load->helper('number_helper');
    $post_limit = get_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));

    # If the post limit is -1 (i.e. unlimited) return true as we 
    # can't exceed the upload size
    if ($post_limit == -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] <= $post_limit;
}
```